# When background is added to text in cell of the table, text resolution will be bad

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable which has some records, and I want to add red background to the one cell. But when I add background to the cell with javascript, Text will be very bad. What should I change to fix it ?

[resolution bad text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw2eM.png)

[in excel expected solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKpHi.png)

I searched many resources but I didn't find anything. Some people say it depends my screen. But when I tried with classic excel(text + red background), text is very good therefore I didn't think my screen causes to the bad resolution.

Comment: Better add some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.